# Grouping buttons with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, button, grouping, android-constraintlayout

I can't make a group of buttons visible or invisible.

Target is that when clicking on one of the buttons, a group goes invisible and the next group of buttons becomes visible. Using migration to androidX.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="206dp" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:id="@+id/group4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="button5,button6" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I make the group with their buttons and other elements, buttons are visible.

Comment: what code you have written on button click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.. when click both button not visible.

```
 Group group;
 group=findViewById(R.id.group4);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            group.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, I figured out this some days ago. When using attributes in desing mode dont see result. It looks like it is as some kind of big in Android Studio. Finally, when i run code I saw result.

Comment: yes but invisible not remove space it contain space when you used gone then it remove space.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this in your `activity`

```
Group group4 = findViewById(R.id.group4);
Group group5 = findViewById(R.id.group5);
 ......
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        group4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        group5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
});
```